# How to highlight pdf based on pattern matching from ubuntu terminal?

Tags: command-line, pdf, pdftk

Aware that pdf can be read into the terminal using The Poppler Developers tools.

One of the tools which helps in checking for a pattern in the pdf and then printing in the terminal is

```
pdfgrep
```

Suppose say, I am interested in the word "Happy" in a set of PDF files in the current working directory. I also wish to get the context in which Happy word has been used in all the PDFs. We can use the following code to print 2 lines above and 2 lines below the word 'Happy' in all the PDF in the directory using the following code

```
pdfgrep 'Happy' * -H  -A 2 -B 2
```

Now my question is not this. I want to highlight the word Happy in all the PDF present in my directory through the terminal

I am adding the required output to make things more clear.

[In the attached PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jEyS7VFm31mpgUKyeDahCWBTt3biJK5W) which is one among the many in the directory, I need this kind of output to be made.

Any ideas on ways to execute this?